# Java number sign and asterisk

Tags: java, loops

Please help me :( I'd like to try a right angle alternate asterisk and number sign. But I only got this output: (I can't place here the number sign)

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

what i want is this if i enter 6 the output is:

```
*
 #
  *
   #
    *
     #
```

Sample if i enter 3 the output is:

```
*
 #
  *
```

Here's the code that I programmed:

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        

    int x=0;

     System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        x = in.nextInt();   

    for( int i = 1; i <= x; i++ ){


    for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
        System.out.print("*");

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
      }
```

Comment: Does your code even print alternate symbols? Try doing some work over alternating the symbols at-least. Ignore the pattern for a while. Then come up with something that's not working.

Comment: Sorry im newbie, so what can i do to got this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep printing space in inner loop and once it come out from the inner loop print `*` and/or `#` accordingly.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);        

    int x=0;

    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    x = in.nextInt();

    for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){

        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
           System.out.print(" ");   
        }

        if(i%2==1)
        {
           System.out.println("*");
        }else
        {
           System.out.println("#"); 
        }
    }
```

[**>>>Demo Link<<<**](https://ideone.com/pezNEK)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `"*"` by

```
j < i-1 ? " " : (i % 2 != 0 ? "*" : "#")
```

This will write the correct output, by testing the row and col position and writing the correct char.

Comment: I've just tried, it works correctly. Did you try?

Comment: @nullpointer: you say *Please read the question carefully, the patterns are different*. In my answer, there are both of the patterns, as you should have seen (I've your read it?). Now that you understand your doubts were wrong, you speak about comments. Again, you have not read carefully my answer: I had written explanations about how it works, just behind the code. Now, asking to give a remote java compiler link is ... awesome for 20 chars of code: I've told you it works for me. If you don't trust me, just try by yourself. Like I did. Keep your doubts and talk about facts.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `char` array that would hold the symbols. You can have a counter variable and use it in such a way that at each iteration it would point the index of the character you want to be displayed.

```
char sym[] = {'#', '*'};
int n = user's input, i,j,c=0;
for(i = 1; i<=n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j<i; j++)
        System.out.print(" "); //space

    System.out.print(sym[c]);
    c = (c+1)%2;

    System.out.println();
}
```

**NOTE:** Notice the way I'm using the variable `c` to basically hold an integer and finding the remainder when it's divided by 2 to get the index.

This is a very bad idea for big input values of n but will work for the ones of the kind that you've used.

Answer (score 0):

Just have condition for odd and even value, place **#** on **even** and * on **odd** and start value of j from 1 and the condition for inner for loop should have **j<=i**

i just changed your code to look like below:

```
for( int i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ){
                  for( int j = 1; j <=i; j++ ){
                        if(i==j){
                              if(i%2==0){
                                    System.out.print("#");
                              }else{
                                    System.out.print("*");
                              }
                        }else{
                              System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                  }
                  System.out.println();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    int x = in.nextInt();

    String spaces = "";
    boolean star = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        System.out.println(spaces + (star ? "*" : "#"));

        spaces += " ";
        star = !star;
    }
}
```

This should do the trick, quick & easy.